# How to deny access to files when people surf for them?

Tags: .htaccess

I have a .htaccess file in my /cache/ directory. The .htaccess content is

```
Deny from all
```

This stops web visitors from being able to read the files inside /cache/ as they get a "Forbidden" message if they visit the direct URL.

Problem is, it also stops my web server from accessing the file so my application breaks.

What's the solution in this case?

Answer (score 0):

If the cache directory and the web server are different machines, you will not be able to access the files. In that case, you should use a secure protocol like sftp.

If, as is more probable, `/cache/` is on the same machine as your web server, simply use local paths instead of URLs:

For instance use 
`file_get_contents("/path/to/cache/file.txt")`
or
`file_put_contents("path/to/cache/file.txt", $contents)`
instead of
`file_get_contents("www.example.com/cache/file.txt")`
or
`file_put_contents("www.example.com/cache/file.txt", $contents)`.

Comment: They are on the same machine. When you say local paths, what do you mean? my .htaccess is here `example.com/cache/.htaccess` and the contents of the .htaccess file is `Deny from all`

Comment: @henrywright What language are you using to build the application? If it is php, then you would use `include` or `file_get_contents`, depending on how you want to load the content. I can improve my answer if you include the part of the code that is breaking.

Comment: file_get_contents() is the function I'm using. The file inside /cache/ is basically JSON data

Comment: @henrywright If you use `file_get_contents('/path/to/docroot/cache/filename')` it should work just fine.

Comment: whilst /cache/ is on the same machine (that's where I'm saving the data), where I'm getting the data from is an external source so I must use the absolute path like this `file_get_contents( 'http://this-is-an-external-website.com' )` - I'm saving data to /cache/ using `file_put_contents()`